# VIDEOJS: ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentResolution' of null

Tags: javascript, php

I try to use VAST instream video ads in VibeJS (Player based on VideoJS). I get a strange issue and error messages:

````
```Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var```
```error parsererror```
````

The issue: The ads play, but ONLY for logged in users. Then I also get this message:

````
```video.js:1 VIDEOJS: ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentResolution' of null
    at constructor.s.update (vibe.plugins.js:4)
    at e.n (video.js:2)
    at HTMLDivElement.n (video.js:2)
    at HTMLDivElement.X.n.dispatcher.n.dispatcher (video.js:1)
    at K (video.js:1)
    at e.trigger (video.js:2)
    at e.o.updateSrc (vibe.plugins.js:4)
    at e.<anonymous> (vibe.plugins.js:4)
    at n (video.js:2)```

For guests, the player loads without ads and only in low quality without enhanced controls. This is really weird.

I tried to modify and remove code from the ads section. Also I rewrote the players files multiple times. I'm using the newest version of my video CMS.
````

Error messages, see above. I want VAST ads to play normally for all users in a normal player.

I can provide the full player and player implementation files, attaching the code here doesn't work because its too much.

Here when I put in a VAST tag:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var`
When playing:
`Uncaught (in promise) DOMException`

Player implementation:

````
    {
    global $video;
    /* Render VideoJs Player */
    $ads   = _vjsads();
    $embed = '<video id="tvideo" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="auto" poster="' . $thumb . '" data-setup=\'{"controls": true, "autoplay": false, "fluid": true, "aspectRatio": "16:9", "errorDisplay": false, "resizeManager": false,  "muted": false,  "playbackRates": [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2]}\'>';

      if(!empty($extra)) {
    /* Unset sd/hd */     
    if(isset($extra['sd'])) {unset($extra['sd']);}  
    if(isset($extra['hd'])) {unset($extra['hd']);}
    foreach ($extra as $size=>$link) {
    $embed .= '<source src="' . $link . '" type=\'video/mp4\' label =\''._lang(str_replace('hd','',$size).'p').'\' res=\''.$size.'\'/>';```
````

Comment: Without the relevant section of the code we cannot help you...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) And the perfect question And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) SO is **not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service** You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.